# make a function helper with react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm new to react / redux

When I doing the project in jquery
I will make some functions like this:

```
errorHandle (code) {
  if(code = 1){
    $('.popUpA').show()
  }
  ...
}

callAPI (){
  //Do AJAX call
  //If Error , call errorHandle()
}
```

In the new project,

I use the axios to call API in the api helper

```
export function getDataList(){
  //axios....
}

export function getData(){
  //axios....
}
```

And I use the Store to trigger the show/hide popUp , I will use `dispatch(showPopup())` and `dispatch(showPopup(hide))` in component

But I want that if api function have error , will pass the response in to the errorHandler , then dispatch the showPopup. I don't have idea how to add this into the exported function.

Any suggestion or example?

Comment: You can checkout http://github.com/orar/questrar to handle request states

Answer (score 0):

this is my abstraction of axios request, I use it in services that are used with Redux:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { API } from '../../constants';

import { revokeAuthAction } from ;

export const getAuth = () => {
 // Auth logic
};

/**
 * Create an Axios Client with defaults
 */
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: API.BASEURL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: getAuth(),
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': 1728000,
    // 'X-Authorization-JWT':
  },
});

/**
 * Request Wrapper with default success/error actions
 */
const request = (options) => {
  const onSuccess = (response) => options.raw ? response : response.data;
    // console.debug('Request Successful!', response);
    // If options.raw is true, return all response

  const onError = (error) => {
    // console.error('Request Failed:', error.config);

    if (error.response) {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        // console.error('Unauthorized');
        store.dispatch(revokeAuthAction());
      } else {
        // Request was made but server responded with something
        // other than 2xx
        // console.error('Status:', error.response.status);
        // console.error('Data:', error.response.data);
        // console.error('Headers:', error.response.headers);
      }
    } else {
      // Something else happened while setting up the request
      // triggered the error
      // console.error('Error Message:', error.message);
    }

    return Promise.reject(error.response || error.message);
  };

  return client(options)
    .then(onSuccess)
    .catch(onError); // in realtà non catcho un bel niente perchè ritorno Promise.reject e quindi il giro ricomincia
};

export default request;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more library to handle redux async action calls. I use redux-thunk another well known library is redux-saga. With redux thunk you will add a middleware to redux and this way you can create async action creators which return a function, and they can call other action creators depending of the result of the async call.

You add the middleware this way:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

And your action creator will be something like this:

```
export function requestDataList() {
  return function (dispatch: Function, getState: Function) {
    return getDataList().then(resp => {
      dispatch(dataListReceived(resp.data));
    }).catch(error => {
      dispatch(showPopup(title, error.message));
    });
  };
}
```

So if your getDataList retrun an axios promise, on success it will call an action wit the result. On error it can call the error dialog.